# Marionette CompositeView not responding to changes in collection

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to create a customized todo list, loosely based on the Backbone todoMVC tutorial app.

I've created a `CompositeView` that shows a collection using separate `ItemView`s. My understanding is that whenever a new model is added to the CompositeView's collection, it will automatically generate an ItemView for that model and add it to the CompositeView's `el`.

However, this doesn't work for me. I've confirmed that the model gets created in the database, but the view fails to update automatically. I can see the Todo when I refresh the page. I've even tried setting up the `collectionEvents` hash to watch for any models being added, but those methods (newTask, collectionFetched) never fired.

Here's my code for the CompositeView:

```
app.Views.TodosCompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  template: '#todo-list-template',
  childView: app.Views.TodoItemView,
  childViewContainer: 'tbody',
  emptyView: app.Views.TodoEmptyView,

  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new app.Collections.Todos();
    this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
    this.collection.fetch();
  },

  collectionEvents: {
    'add': 'newTask',
    'reset': 'collectionFetched'
  },

  newTask: function() {
    console.log('new todo added');
  },

  collectionFetched: function() {
    console.log('collection was fetched');
  }
```

And the show method in my route:

```
app.Views.todosListView = new app.Views.TodosCompositeView();
app.mainRegion.show(app.Views.todosListView);
```

A similar question mentioned passing the collection as an option in the constructor for the compositeView, i.e. `new app.Views.TodosCompositeView({collection:todos})` That didn't help either.

Comment: And how is the new models being added to the collection?

Comment: I've tried using both `this.collection.add` and `this.collection.create` to add a model. Neither fires the callback for the add event listener.

Comment: Then probably the collection instance you're adding the models to is not the same instance as the collection you're listening for events to.